# List of all items from queryset with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, regex, django, beautifulsoup

I have Django project with field, with contents (from QuerySet):

```
<p><b>Name and LastName</b><br />
Work Title<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
<p><b>Name and LastName 1</b><br />
Work Title1 <br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
<p><b>Name and LastName 2</b><br />
Work Title 2<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
```

But I want to have text in this format, with (-):

```
Name and LastName - Work Title
Name and LastName 2 - Work Title 2
Name and LastName 3 - Work Title 3
```

Here is my code, but I get only first item, but I want to have array with items:

```
text_list = self.texts.filter(code='ON')
for i in text_list:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(i.text_en, "html.parser")
    aa = soup.p.get_text(separator=" - ", strip=True)
return [aa]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `p` tags. From the example you provided, you can try like this:

```
source = """<p><b>Name and LastName</b><br />
Work Title<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
<p><b>Name and LastName 1</b><br />
Work Title1 <br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
<p><b>Name and LastName 2</b><br />
Work Title 2<br /><span class="text-spacer"></span>
</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
ary = [p.get_text(separator=' - ', strip=True) for p in soup.find_all('p')]
```

The `ary` will be:

```
[u'Name and LastName - Work Title',
 u'Name and LastName 1 - Work Title1',
 u'Name and LastName 2 - Work Title 2']
```